# is it possible to make a code to combine several blender files and make several combinations of them?

Tags: source-code

if I want to make an avatar and I have 10 bodies, 10 clothes, 10 weapons and 5 backgrounds and each part is saved separately in a blender file. Is it possible to create a code that will create a combination of those files, those parts, and output the finished files.

> Blockquote

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know of any program that would directly accept a blend file for avatars, so I think you would be better off putting all assets in one blend file, and hiding/unhiding individual assets as desired. Most, if not all, file exporters in Blender allow you to export only the selection, which, as far as I know, is only considered to include visible objects.

To make things easier to find, you might group similar assets (i.e. assets that would clash with each other as they apply to the same body part) into labeled collections (for example, “Hats”, “Facewear”, “Shirts”, etc).